# jQuery form validation regex, start with and symbol count

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

I'm validating phone number, it's must be `"+3706 XXXXXXX"`, start with `"+3706" + 8 digits`

My regex is `/^(+3706)(8{d})/` , but it not walidating, what is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex should be:

```
/^(\+3706) *(\d{8})$/
```

`+` needs to be escaped in regex and to match 8 digits you need to use `\d{8}`

#### Working Demo: http://regex101.com/r/gU2cF4